# How to create a macro for a new numbered environment, with "spread" text?

Tags: spacing, environments, boxes

I am looking to create a new environment in LATeX for typesetting some verses of a poem (non-English). I would like each verse to have text spread to occupy the entire width of the longest verse. To illustrate, consider the minimum working example below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\versewd}
\settowidth{\versewd}{adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}

\begin{tabular}{p{\versewd}l}
    \makebox[\versewd][s]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}     &                \\
    \makebox[\versewd][s]{consectetuer adipiscing elit} & (1) \\
    \makebox[\versewd][s]{Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac}        &                \\
    \makebox[\versewd][s]{adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}    & (2) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This generates output that looks like:
[image: Output of the MWE]

This is exactly what I want, but I would like to create an environment that does that. I would like the code to look much simpler, something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
    \myitem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}{consectetuer adipiscing elit}       
    \myitem{Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac}{adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

I'd be grateful for any pointers in this direction. My initial searches of creating new environments did not come up with anything helpful enough towards solving this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution acts by

1. absorbing the entire poem;
2. measuring each verse at its natural width, keeping track of the maximum width;
3. printing each verse in a spread box.

Stanzas are separated by a blank line in the input, verses by `\\`. Numbers are added at the end of each stanza.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewEnviron{spreadverse}
 {
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % no indent
  \hbadness=\c_ten_thousand   % don't show underfull box messages
  \raman_spreadverse:V \BODY
 }

%% variables
\dim_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim
\int_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int
\seq_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq
\seq_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq
\seq_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq
\box_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_verse_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \raman_spreadverse:n
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim
  \int_zero:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq { \par } { #1 }
  % measure the verses
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq
   {
    \raman_spreadverse_measure:n { ##1 }
   }
  % typeset the verses
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq
   {
    \raman_spreadverse_print:n { ##1 }
    \int_incr:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int
    \nolinebreak
    \quad
    ( \int_to_arabic:n {\l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int} )
    \par
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \raman_spreadverse:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \raman_spreadverse_measure:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_verse_box { ##1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn
       { \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim }
       { \box_wd:N \l_raman_spreadverse_verse_box }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \raman_spreadverse_print:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq
     {
      \makebox[\l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim][s]{##1}
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq { \\* }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadverse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
consectetuer adipiscing elit

Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac \\
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{spreadverse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version that allows an optional argument for using a different environment enclosing the verses (default `center`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe} % just for the example

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewEnviron{spreadverse}[1][center]
 {
  \begin{#1}
  \hbadness=\c_ten_thousand
  \raman_spreadverse:V \BODY
  \end{#1}
 }

%% variables
\dim_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim
\int_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int
\seq_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq
\seq_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq
\seq_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq
\box_new:N \l_raman_spreadverse_verse_box

\cs_new_protected:Nn \raman_spreadverse:n
 {
  \dim_zero:N \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim
  \int_zero:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq { \par } { #1 }
  % measure the verses
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq
   {
    \raman_spreadverse_measure:n { ##1 }
   }
  % typeset the verses
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_stanzas_seq
   {
    \raman_spreadverse_print:n { ##1 }
    \int_incr:N \l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int
    \nolinebreak
    \makebox[0pt][l]
     {
      \quad
      ( \int_to_arabic:n {\l_raman_spreadverse_stanza_int} )
     }
    \par
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \raman_spreadverse:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \raman_spreadverse_measure:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq
   {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_verse_box { ##1 }
    \dim_set:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim
     {
      \dim_max:nn
       { \l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim }
       { \box_wd:N \l_raman_spreadverse_verse_box }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \raman_spreadverse_print:n
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_verses_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq
     {
      \makebox[\l_raman_spreadverse_width_dim][s]{##1}
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_raman_spreadverse_printverses_seq { \\* }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{spreadverse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
consectetuer adipiscing elit

Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac \\
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{spreadverse}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{spreadverse}[flushleft]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\
consectetuer adipiscing elit

Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac \\
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
\end{spreadverse}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Note that in this version the numbers don't take part in the centering (it could be modified so that they do).

[image]

Comment: This is truly brilliant and infinitely helpful! Thanks for taking the time to do this, really. May I request you to post some links where I can understand your code better? Should I look up Latex3 and/or xparse? Really grateful to you @egreg!

Comment: @KarthikRaman Yes, the documentation for `expl3` is what you need: `texdoc expl3` and `texdoc interface3`.

Comment: With newer versions of `expl3`, `\c_ten_thousand` should be replaced by `10000~`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewenvironment{verse}
{\par\addvspace{10pt}\hsize12cm\parindent0pt
\parfillskip0pt
\emergencystretch\maxdimen
\def\par{\ifhmode\unskip\rlap{\quad\refstepcounter{enumi} (\theenumi)}\fi
\endgraf}%
\def\\{\endgraf}}
{\par\let\par\endgraf\addvspace{10pt}}
\begin{document}


\noindent\rule{12cm}{2pt}

\begin{verse}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\\
    consectetuer adipiscing elit

    Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac\\
    adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.

\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution, @DavidCarlisle. A couple of minor issues: the length setting is manual, instead of fetching it from the longest line in the text. I have a simple workaround for that, although (using the same `versewd` length from my MWE. The main issue I have is, I am unable to enclose this environment within `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` -- the entire formatting is sort of lost (all text gets centered). It would be very helpful if you could suggest a workaround. Thanks!

Comment: the length setting, just replace `12cm` by `\mylength` and then set that via `\newlength\mylength \settowidth\mylength{the longest line of text}` easiest way to adjust the horizontal setting would be to add \leftskip1cm or whatever left margin you need. If you don't need page breaking you could put it in a minipage of width `\mylength` (or 12cm) and then center that.